# How to create a button to generate a pdf file and update record on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a button on sheet1 to print the sheet 1"Template" as pdf and update the record on sheet2"Record" by filling in the next empty row but there seem to be bugs in my formula... Please help

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim invoiceRng As Range
    'Setting range to be printed
    Dim FPath As String
    Dim FName As String
    Dim Amendment As String
    Dim eRow As String
    Set invoiceRng = Range("A1:F61")
    FPath = "D:\"
    FName = Sheets("Template").Range("F3")
    Amendment = Sheets("Template").Range("F4")
    'setting the fulli qualified name. The resultent pdf will be saved where the main file exists.
    invoiceRng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=FPath & FName & "-" & Amendment & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    'Find last row
    eRow = Sheets("Record").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row
    'Copy the data
    Sheets("Template").Range("B8").Copy
    'Activate the destination worksheet
    Sheets("Record").Activate
    'Select the target range
    Range("B", eRow).Select
    'Paste in the target desitnation
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created " _

End Sub
```

Comment: "there seem to be bugs in my formula" is not a useful description of the *specific* problem(s) you're having with your code.  Don't make us guess what the issue is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a few questions. What's the name of the worksheet containing this code? What's the name of the worksheet where `invoiceRng` is located or at least is it in the same worksheet containing the code? Are worksheets `Template` and `Record` in the same workbook as the code? What is in cells `F3` and `F4`? Why are you calculating `eRow` in column `A`, but writing to column `B`? Which line throws an error, if any?

Comment: @VBasic
Worksheet"Template" and "Record" are in the same workbook. "Template" is the worksheet that contains the above code. What I want to do is to generate a pdf copy of worksheet "Template" and record the details on the worksheet "Record". But my code only works until I added the below part for filling in the next empty row on worksheet"Record":
    eRow = Sheets("Record").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ...etc

Comment: @Tim Williams
sorry for being unclear. It works for the parts generating pdf but there is a bug for updating the record on another worksheet:
eRow = Sheets("Record").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row

Comment: The line should be: `eRow = Sheets("Record").Cells(Sheets("Record").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`.

Comment: "there is a bug" is still not particularly useful - what error do you see, or what's happening when it gets to that part of the code?

Comment: It's `xlUp` not `x1Up`  If you use `Option Explicit` then it will warn you about these types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

### Export Range to PDF

- If you write the code fully qualified, you can run it using a command button on any sheet.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub exportToPDF()

    Const FPath As String = "D:\"
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Source Worksheet
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("Template")
    ' Define Invoice Range.
    Dim invoiceRng As Range
    Set invoiceRng = src.Range("A1:F61")
    ' Define File Name.
    Dim FName As String
    FName = src.Range("F3")
    ' Define Amendment.
    Dim Amendment As String
    Amendment = src.Range("F4")
    ' Export to PDF
    invoiceRng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=FPath & FName & "-" & Amendment & ".pdf", _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=True

    ' Target Worksheet.
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.Worksheets("Record")
    ' Find First Empty Row.
    Dim eRow As Long
    eRow = tgt.Cells(tgt.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ' Copy value.
    tgt.Cells(eRow, "B").Value = src.Range("B8").Value
    ' Or:
    'tgt.Range("B" & eRow).Value = srcRange("B8").Value
    
    ' Confirmation message with file info
    
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created "

End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Template`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    exportToPDF
End Sub
```